# Why don't I need to specify undefined as a return type?

Tags: typescript, oop

I have a class with setter and getters, for example:

```
class Car {

  get color() : string {
    return this._color ?? undefined
  }

  set color(color: string) {
     this._color = color
  }

  private _color: string

}
```

Why don't I need to specify it like this?

```
get color(): string | undefined {...}
```

Because if I start the class but I don't set the color attribute and I get undefined:

```
myCar = new Car()

myCar.color //=> undefined
```

Comment: Turn on strict mode (or at least `strictNullChecks`), then you get `Property '_color' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.` Note that there's not much point having accessors until they actually *do* something.

Comment: but how could the constructor look like, when I don't know the color yet

Comment: If you don't know the color at construction time, then it *should* be optional - `private _color?: string;`, then you get the warnings you expect in the getter: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYCdoG8BQ1oAcEEsBuYALgKbQD6wA9iJQgPwBc0EhuAdgOYDcq60HxQtCo0EACgCU0Ji3YcUfDAkEBXBG2iEAFjggA6CtVo8MAX14YIg4UfEjaM1jk5S0Gd9t0H7SALw3RE2hzcyA. But it might be simpler to wait until you have the information you need, then this could just be written `class Car { constructor(public color: string) {} }`.